# How to delete by criteria in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a student table and want to delete all students in a class.

So my sql query would look like:

```
delete from student where classId = 333
```

How can I do this using hibernate with criteria?

I need this so I can put in one of my base classes to use by any DAO objects that extend from it. So I can make this generic across all of my DAO objects.

Currently I have created a generic method that will taken in the Student Object - calls the find method that uses the criteria to get the list and then I do a batch delete under one transaction as follows:

```
public boolean deleteByCriteria(Object deleteObject) {
    List deleteObjectList = find(deleteObject);
    if (deleteObjectList == null)
        return false;
    return deleteAll(deleteObjectList);
}

public boolean deleteAll(List deleteObjectList) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Entered BaseSchoolRollBookDAO -> delete");
        logger.debug("Object for batch deletion [" + deleteObjectList + "]");
    }
    boolean result = false;
    Transaction tx = null;
    // Get CurrentSession from HibernateUtils
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession();
    // Start transaction
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // Create new Criteria to be passed
    try {
        int flushCount = 0;
        for (Object deleteObject : deleteObjectList) {
            session.delete(deleteObject);
            flushCount++;

            if (flushCount % 20 == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }           

        tx.commit();
        result = true;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.fatal("Exception in executing batch Delete query", e);
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback(); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wonder, will deleting in a loop cause performance problems?

Answer (score 76):

For **deleting** data, use HQL which is **the best option**.
I think **Criteria's** main purpose is for **retrieving** data only.

This one is with `Criteria`:

```java
Student student = (Student ) session.createCriteria(Student.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("classId", classId)).uniqueResult();
session.delete(student);
```

And this one is simple HQL query:

```java
String hql = "delete from Student where classId= :classId";
session.createQuery(hql).setString("classId", classId).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Just a note for other people. If you use the Hibernate version suggested by Jamshid, you still have to store the transaction : tx = session.beginTransaction(); and then execute a commit : tx.commit(); in order to get it working.

Comment: Does that criteria actually work? It looks strange, getting student as uniqueResult then deleting that.

Comment: I have moved away from Hibernate and sorry to put this comment after really long time but I don't think the above hibernate criteria example will work because that is the main reason why I asked this question and why I had to do the way I am doing it in my example.

Comment: This isn't a particularly good solution, you will need to go to the db to retrieve the results and then send a subsequent delete instruction.  What if you have to delete 1M rows?  You really don't want to pull them all in to memory to only reissue the query back to the DB.

Comment: @Michael, you are absolutely right... I mentioned Criteria is meant for retrieving and i just answered how to achieve that even with Criteria while saying HQL is best option...

Comment: But will HQL work in case of compound key? I want to delete multiple entities that have ids from the given list. ID is an `@Embeddable` class.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily achieve by following simple hibernate as follows,

```
Session session=getSession();  
String hql = "delete from Student where classId= :id"; 
session.createQuery(hql).setLong("id", new Integer(id)).executeUpdate();
```

for details [refer](http://www.smashplus.info/2012/11/delete-query-in-hibernate-example.html)

Comment: why do you use `setLong` with `new Integer()` ?

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm pretty late to the party but if you happen to use JPA 2.1 you can do it this way -

> https://thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/

```
 public void deleteOrder(Double amount) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // create delete
    CriteriaDelete<Order> delete = cb.
     createCriteriaDelete(Order.class);

    // set the root class
    Root e = delete.from(Order.class);

    // set where clause
    delete.where(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(e.get("amount"), amount));

    // perform update
    this.em.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is the best way and better than @Jama Asatillayev 's answer.
Because you dont have to retrieve the persistent object first.

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setId(37);
session.delete(product);
```

And hibernate will run:

```
Hibernate: delete from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ID=?
```

More details: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Comment: Well, it doesn't directly answer the question "How can I do this using Hibernate with criteria?" ... but does implement the simplest, pure-Hibernate solution for deleting a single entity by id.

Comment: @Lambart You're right but probably "with criteria" means "I want to use objects" here. So I keep the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should upgrade your hibernate version to a version that implements JPA 2.1 (Hibernate starts JPA 2.1 on version 4.3.11.Final - [Hibernate Downloads](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/))

Once you have upgraded, you can use **CriteriaDelete** to do what you want.
here is a small example:
[Example](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/)

Answer (score 3):

You Can use criteria for in condition

```
public Integer deleteByFieldIn(String Field, Iterable<?> values) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaDelete<T> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(getDomainClass());
    Root<T> e = delete.from(getDomainClass());
    delete.where(cb.in(e.get(Field)).value(values));
    return entityManager.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

and You can use same for equal  condition by replacing in to equal like

```
public Integer deleteById(String id) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaDelete<T> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(getDomainClass());
    Root<T> e = delete.from(getDomainClass());
    delete.where(cb.equal(e.get("id"), id));
    return entityManager.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param objects
 */
 public static void deleteAll(List<?> objects) {

            try {
                HibernateEntityManager em = JPA.em().unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
                Session session = em.getSession();
                for (Object o : objects) {
                    session.delete(o);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error("CommonHibernateBD_deleteAll error: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete, you must use the `CriteriaDelete` query. `CriteriaBuilder` ensures that the query is type safe if this use properly. Add a metadata class `Student_` to your method to avoid errors peculiar to `HQL`, `JPQL` or `NativeQuery`.

```
...

private EntityManager em;

...

public void deleteByIdUser(int classId) {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaDelete<Student> deleteQuery = builder.createCriteriaDelete(Student.class);

        Root<Student> studentTable = deleteQuery.from(Student.class);       

        Path<Long> classIdPath = userRoleTable.get(Student_.classId);
        Predicate classIdPredicate = builder.equal(classIdPath, classId);

        deleteQuery.where(classIdPredicate);
        em.createQuery(deleteQuery).executeUpdate();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This info must be added to pom to generate metadata classes for your entities.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is verbose, but avoids redundant `RuntimeExceptions`.

Answer (score -1):

first you need a form with input , the value of the input is model that you have modeled in modelmap, than
make 
delete 
in some link.
than get the id parameter , with 
@requestparam("id")String id

know we got id of the object
and then delete the id
e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="delsubloc",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String DeleteLoc(@RequestParam("id")Long id) {
        PplLocDtlDAO dtl = new PplLocDtlDAO();
        PplLocDtl loc = new PplLocDtl();
        loc.setLocDtlId((long)id);
        dtl.delete(loc);
        return "redirect:/lokasi";
    }
```